# Why my SGD is far off than my linear regression model?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to compare Linear Regression (Normal Equation) with SGD but it looks like SGD is far off. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code

```
x = np.random.randint(100, size=1000)
y = x * 0.10
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x=x, y=y)
print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (slope,intercept))
#slope is 0.100000 and intercept is 1.61435309565e-11
```

And here's my SGD

```
x = x.reshape(1000,1)
clf = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
clf.fit(x, y, coef_init=0, intercept_init=0)

print(clf.intercept_)
print(clf.coef_)

#[  1.46746270e+10]
#[  3.14999003e+10]
```

I would have thought that the `coef` and `intercept` would be almost the same as the data is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run this code, I got an overflow error. I suspect you're having the same problem, but for some reason, it's not throwing an error.

If you scale down the features, everything works as expected. Using `scipy.stats.linregress`:

```
>>> x = np.random.random(1000) * 10
>>> y = x * 0.10
>>> slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x=x, y=y)
>>> print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (slope,intercept))
slope is 0.100000 and intercept is -2.22044604925e-15
```

Using `linear_model.SGDRegressor`:

```
>>> clf.fit(x[:,None], y)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01, fit_intercept=True,
       l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling', loss='squared_loss',
       n_iter=5, penalty='l2', power_t=0.25, random_state=None,
       shuffle=False, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (clf.coef_, clf.intercept_[0]))
slope is 0.099763 and intercept is 0.00163353754797
```

The value for `slope` is a little lower, but I'd guess that's because of the regularization.

Comment: I was wondering why `np.random.randint(100, size=1000)` doesn't work as x? As that's the data I intended to use. It's the amount of total bill a customer likely to pay for a meal.

Comment: @toy, data nearly always needs to be scaled to [-1,1] or [0,1] before using ML techniques. See the [Practial Tips](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/sgd.html#tips-on-practical-use) section of the SGD documentation. Also, you will want far more than 5 iterations with only 1000 examples. See that same section.

Answer (score 0):

I used `GridSearchCV()` over parameters and found out that, apart from the fine-tuning hyper-parameters, the main issue is the `loss` argument which by default is `'squared_error'`, so just set it to `'huber'` within your SGD model/pipeline like:  `SGDRegressor(loss='huber')`

A possible explanation based on [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) is as follows:

> ...The ‘squared_error’ refers to the ordinary least squares fit. ‘huber’ modifies ‘squared_error’ to **focus less on getting outliers correct** by switching from squared to linear loss past a distance of epsilon. ...

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(321)
x = np.random.random(1000) * 10
y = x * 0.10

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x=x, y=y)
print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (slope,intercept))
#slope is 0.100000 and intercept is -1.1102230246251565e-16


from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
x = x.reshape(1000,1)
clf = SGDRegressor(loss='huber',  random_state=123)
clf.fit(x, y)

print("slope is %f and intercept is %s" % (clf.coef_, clf.intercept_[0]))
#slope is 0.099741 and intercept is 0.0017359301382874714
```

PS I used `GridSearchCV`as follows:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Create the pipeline
sgd_pipeline = Pipeline([('SGD', SGDRegressor())])

# Define the hyperparameter grid
param_grid = {
    'SGD__loss': ['squared_loss', 'huber', 'epsilon_insensitive'],
    'SGD__penalty': ['l2', 'l1', 'elasticnet'],
    'SGD__alpha': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01],
    'SGD__l1_ratio': [0.15, 0.25, 0.5]
}

# Perform grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(sgd_pipeline, param_grid, cv=5)
grid_search.fit(x, y)

# Get the best model
best_sgd_reg = grid_search.best_estimator_

# Print the best hyperparameters
print("Best Hyperparameters:")
print(grid_search.best_params_)

# Fit the best model on the training data
best_sgd_reg.fit(x, y)
```