# SGDRegressor() constantly not increasing validation performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, gradient-descent

The model fit of my `SGDRegressor` wont increase or decrease its performance on the validation set (`test`) after around 20'000 training records. Even if I try to switch `penalty`, `early_stopping (True/False)` or `alpha`,`eta0` to extremely high or low levels, there is no change in the behavior of the "stuck" validation score `test`.

[image]

I used `StandardScaler` and shuffled the data for training- and testset before.

```
train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=85, shuffle=True)

print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
>>>(336144, 10) (144063, 10)
>>>(336144,) (144063,)
```

Is anything wrong with my validation code or is the behavior explainable because of a limitation dealing on training-data that `SGDRegressor` has?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


scores_test = []
scores_train = []
my_rng = range(10,len(X_train),30000)
for m in my_rng:
    print(m)
    modelSGD = SGDRegressor(alpha=0.00001, penalty='l1')
    modelSGD.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
    
    ypred_train = modelSGD.predict(X_train[:m])
    ypred_test = modelSGD.predict(X_test)
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], ypred_train)
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ypred_test)
    scores_train.append(mse_train)
    scores_test.append(mse_test)
```

How can I "force" `SGDRegressor` to respect a larger amount of training data and change its performance on the `test` data?

**Edit:**
I am trying to visualize that the model does not change its score on `test` after being trained by 30'000 or 300'000 records. That's the reason why I'm initializing the SGDRegressor within the loop, so it is completely newly trained in every iteration.

As asked by @Nikaido, these are the models `coef_`, `intercept_` after fitting:

```
trainsize: 10, coef:  [ 0.81815135  2.2966633   1.61231584 -0.00339933 -3.03094922  0.12757874  -2.60874563  1.52383531  0.3250487  -0.61251297], intercept:  [50.77553038]
trainsize: 30010, coef:  [ 0.19097587 -0.35854903 -0.16142221  0.11281925 -0.66771756  0.55912533   0.90462141 -1.417289    0.50487032 -1.42423654], intercept:  [83.28458307]
trainsize: 60010, coef:  [ 0.09848169 -0.1362008  -0.15825232 -0.4401373   0.31664536  0.04960247  -0.37299047  0.6641436   0.02782047 -1.15355052], intercept:  [80.87163096]
trainsize: 90010, coef:  [-0.00923631  0.5845441   0.28485334 -0.29528061 -0.30643056  1.20320208   1.9723999  -0.47707621  1.25355186 -2.04990825], intercept:  [85.17812028]
trainsize: 120010, coef:  [-0.04959943 -0.15744169 -0.17071373 -0.20829149 -1.38683906  2.18572481   1.43380752 -1.48133799  2.18962484 -3.41135224], intercept:  [86.40188522]
trainsize: 150010, coef:  [ 0.56190926  0.05052168  0.22624504  0.55751301 -0.50829818  1.27571154   1.49847285 -0.15134682  1.30017967 -0.88259823], intercept:  [83.69264344]
trainsize: 180010, coef:  [ 0.17765624  0.1137466   0.15081498 -0.51520765 -1.00811419 -0.13203398   1.28565565 -0.03594421 -0.08053252 -2.31793746], intercept:  [85.21824705]
trainsize: 210010, coef:  [-0.53937513 -0.33872786 -0.44854466  0.70039384 -0.77073389  0.4361326   0.88175392 -0.32460908  0.5141777  -1.5123801 ], intercept:  [82.75353293]
trainsize: 240010, coef:  [ 0.70748011 -0.08992019  0.25365326  0.61999278 -0.29374005  0.25833863  -0.00485613 -0.21211637  0.19286126 -1.09503691], intercept:  [85.76414815]
trainsize: 270010, coef:  [ 0.73787648  0.30155102  0.44013832 -0.2355825   0.26255699  1.55410066   0.4733571   0.85352683  1.4399516  -1.73360843], intercept:  [84.19473044]
trainsize: 300010, coef:  [ 0.04861321 -0.35446415 -0.17774692 -0.1060901  -0.5864299   1.03429399   0.57160049 -0.13900199  1.09189946 -1.26298814], intercept:  [83.14797646]
trainsize: 330010, coef:  [ 0.20214825  0.22605839  0.17022397  0.28191112 -1.05982574  0.74025932   0.04981973 -0.27232538  0.72094765 -0.94875017], intercept:  [81.97656309]
```

**Edit2:**
@Nikaido asked for it: This is the distribution of the Data. Very similar distributed train- / testdata features comes due to the origin values that are categories (of a range 1-9) or deconstructed timestamps as NumberOfMonth, DayOfWeek, Hours, Minutes.
The `labels` plot shows a lack of normal distribution around 100. The reason for this: missing values have been replaced by the global average of each category, which was between 80 an 95.

[image]

Further on I have created a plot that shows the validation zoom generated by the code snippet above by changing:

```
my_rng = range(1000,len(X_train)-200000,2000)
```

SGD typical jumping around an optimum is visible. But anyways the tendency of the test-score does not change in any significant way as records of the training-set increase.
[image]

Comment: Your usage within a `for` loo is weird - we normally do not use SGD this way; plus, your `alpha` is very small - always try with the default value(s) first.

Comment: Thank you. @desertnaut Any suggestion how to use SGD in a loop to better visualize the behaviour?  As described, it won't change the behaviour as i change alpha to extreme high or low values, or just leve it at default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Regarding your output, my guess is that your results are so close for the validation set because a linear model like SGDregressor tends to underfit on complex data

To see this you can check the weights outputted by the model at every iteration. You'll see that they are the same or really close

To enhance variability in the output you need to introduce non linearity and complexity

You are obtaining what is referred as "Bias" in machine learning (in contraposition to the "variance")

I think I got it now.

SamAmani In the end I think that the problem is underfitting. And the fact that you are using incremental sizes of the dataset. The model underfit quite fast (which means that the model is stuck at the beginning to a more or less fixed model)

Only the first training output a different result for the test set because it hasn't reached the final model, more or less

**The underlying variability is in the incremental training sets.**
Simply speaking the test results are a more accurate estimate of the performance of the underfitted model. And adding training sample will lead in the end to near results between test and training without improving too much.

You can check the fact that are the incremental datasets of the training to be different from the test set. What you did wrong was to check the stats on all the training set

---

First of all, why are you training on incremental training set size? The strange results are due to the fact that you are training in an incremental fashion your dataset.

When you do this:

```
for m in my_rng:
    modelSGD = SGDRegressor(alpha=0.00001, penalty='l1')
    modelSGD.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
    [...]
```

you are basically training your model in incremental fashion, with this incremental sizes:

```
for m in range(10, 180001, 30000):
    print(m)


10
30010
60010
90010
120010
150010
```

If you are trying to make mini-batch gradient descent, you should split your dataset in independent batches instead of making incremental batches. Something like this:

```
previous = 0
for m in range(30000, 180001, 30000):
    modelSGD.partial_fit(X_train[previous:m], y_train[previous:m])
    previous = m

# training set ranges
0 30000
30000 60000
60000 90000
90000 120000
120000 150000
150000 180000
```

Also note that I am using `partial_fit` method, instead of `fit` (because I am not retraining the model from zero and I am making only a step, iteration of the gradient descent), and I am not going to initialize a new model every time (my sgd initialization is out of the for loop). The full code should be something like this:

```
my_rng = range(0 ,len(X_train), 30000)
previous = 0
modelSGD = SGDRegressor(alpha=0.00001, penalty='l1')
for m in my_rng:
    modelSGD.partial_fit(X_train[previous:m], y_train[previous:m])
    ypred_train = modelSGD.predict(X_train[previous:m])
    ypred_test = modelSGD.predict(X_test)
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train[previous:m], ypred_train)
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ypred_test)
    scores_train.append(mse_train)
    scores_test.append(mse_test)
```

In this way you are simulating **one epoch** mini-batch stochastic gradient. To make more epochs an outer loop is needed

From sklearn:

> SGD allows minibatch (online/out-of-core) learning via the partial_fit
> method. For best results using the default learning rate schedule, the
> data should have zero mean and unit variance.

Details [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.partial_fit)

Comment: Thank you! I know that there is a batch function in SGD and that's the reason why I'm using this model. But thats not the point. My intention was to show you that performance on validation data does not change wether I'm trainig the model using 30'000 or 300'000 training records. and that is what confuses me.

Comment: i have updated the weights data after fitting to my post.

Comment: @SamAmani how is distributed the test data? Maybe they are really similar instances and really close

Comment: @SamAmani anyway, the values are really close if you check better. The values changes very little (0.5/1) also the intercept is stuck around 80~ after the first training. Which means that the model hasn't changed much after the first training

Comment: @SamAmani to check this definitely, try to use a MLPRegressor with two layers and more than two nodes each, you'll see a greater variability

Comment: also, plot the results from the test set at each iterations. I suppose they are really similar and really close, but not the same at each iteration (that cannot be seen from the plot)

Comment: Really apreciate your support @Nikaido! I have re-edited the post thx.

Comment: @SamAmani another thing that I can think of is the y values of your instances. How are they distributed? Anyway doing the shuffle would prevent this kind of biased dataset splitting. I am a bit puzzled. Anyway in some way also the training is "stuck" in a specific range, but wider. Between 167 -174. Instead the test is between  176-177

Comment: which means that the model has become more "sensible" to some specific training instances

Comment: Is it the Distribution of the labels @Nikaido? Afaik SGD Is sensitive on well distributed data. Could the peak be the reason why it is stuck?

Comment: @SamAmani could be the difference in the peaks between training and test. But to be honest I am not sure myself. Are you doing every time the random split? Or is it always the same split?

Comment: I changed `random_state=85` to `19`. Distribution looks exactly the same, MSE curve on `train` slightly different but `test` still the same. Do you think it is worth the effort of working out the label peak arround 90? would take ma a day or two...

Comment: @SamAmani I don't think it would be worth your time. I think that what you got is simply an underfitting of your model. In fact if you check the test more specifically, there is a variability in the test results, but the overal result is worse then the training. And this is expected because the training tends to "overfit" on the training data and therefore to perform better. It is quite common. I think that other things that you can try are: changing the split on which you cut train and set, and try a more complex algorithm

Comment: For example MLPRegressor

Comment: @SamAmani check the update to my answer. I think I got this :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is see the effect of increase in dataset size on the performance of the model. If that is the case as you can see, as the size of data increases the error increases and it reaches stage where with enough data it starts learning (slight decrease in train error) and eventually stabilizing as increase in dataset does not matter now. Also it does not over fit as by default the `SGDRegressor` runs for only 1000 epochs.

I suggest you normalize the data before fitting (0 mean and unit variance).

Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(336144+144063, 10)
y = np.sum(X, axis=1) + np.random.randn(336144+144063)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=85, shuffle=True)

print (X_train.shape, X_test.shape)

scores_test = []
scores_train = []

my_rng = range(5000,len(X_train),10000)
for m in my_rng:
    modelSGD = SGDRegressor(alpha=0.00001, penalty='l1')
    modelSGD.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
    
    ypred_train = modelSGD.predict(X_train[:m])
    ypred_test = modelSGD.predict(X_test)
    mse_train = mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], ypred_train)
    mse_test = mean_squared_error(y_test, ypred_test)
    scores_train.append(mse_train)
    scores_test.append(mse_test)

plt.plot(scores_train)
plt.plot(scores_test)
```

[image]

In case you are trying batch gradient decent follow answer by @Nikaido

Comment: you are exactly right. I wanted to show that my model does not increse validation performance after a small amount of training data. So youre mentoining that my data is the problem and there are more steps to do beside of using `StandardScaler`  on my data?

Answer (score 0):

If you see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559182/10452700) and use `GridSearchCV()`, even by a small modification of your model `SGDRegressor(loss='huber')` (I explained the reason in my answer), you will achieve a better result. I applied on the proposed reproducible example from @mujjiga with the following output:

---

[image: img]